# Laravel missing routes issue

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

i have a problem with my Laravel routes.
if i call the following url: http://laravel/market it works fine, but my site has different languages so i use the LaravelLocalization package and when i call http://laravel/en/market it comes an error:

> Route [market.offers.show] not defined.

i have used:

> php artisan route:list

to see the indexed routes and here is a shortcut of it:

```
    | GET|HEAD                       | market/offers                                                                    | market.offers.index                    | App\Http\Controllers\Front\OffersController@index
    | POST                           | market/offers                                                                    | market.offers.store                    | App\Http\Controllers\Front\OffersController@store
    | GET|HEAD                       | market/offers/bid/{id}                                                           | market.offers.bid                      | App\Http\Controllers\Front\OffersController@bid
    | GET|HEAD                       | market/offers/create                                                             | market.offers.create                   | App\Http\Controllers\Front\OffersController@create
    | GET|HEAD                       | market/offers/history                                                            | market.offers.history                  | App\Http\Controllers\Front\OffersController@history
    | POST                           | market/offers/store/bid                                                          | market.offers.store.bid                | App\Http\Controllers\Front\OffersController@storebid
    | DELETE                         | market/offers/{offers}                                                           | market.offers.destroy                  | App\Http\Controllers\Front\OffersController@destroy
    | GET|HEAD                       | market/offers/{offers}                                                           | market.offers.show                     | App\Http\Controllers\Front\OffersController@show
    | PUT|PATCH                      | market/offers/{offers}                                                           | market.offers.update                   | App\Http\Controllers\Front\OffersController@update
    | GET|HEAD                       | market/offers/{offers}/edit                                                      | market.offers.edit                     | App\Http\Controllers\Front\OffersController@edit
```

on other pages i get the same error for Route [market.offers.create]

why is that ? How can i resolve that ?

Answer (score 0):

in your routes you should add a wildcard for the language for example it will look like `/laravel/{lang}/market`

and then in  your controllers you handle the if the lang is null or not to set the default language

Comment: i have made a prefix: Route::group(['prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale()], function() { }); and inside it are all routes